# Material UI: How can I disable scroll bar in datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, material-design

[image]

how can I disable the scroll bar which is present in the bottom?

for more information, I have already tried `autoPageSize`, but it didn't work.
[autoPageSize docs link](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#props)

```js
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    autoHeight={true}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
    pageSize={5}
    disableSelectionOnClick
    density="compact"
    hideFooterPagination={true}
    hideFooter={true}
    showCellRightBorder={true}
    showColumnRightBorder={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the scrollbar removed by adding "'& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar': {display: 'none' }" in the table style.

```tsx
<DataGrid
        rows={navigate.rows}
        columns={columns}
        getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
        sx={{ '& .MuiDataGrid-row': { marginTop: 1, marginBottom: 1 }, '& .coloured': { textAlign: 'center', color: '#7181AD' },'& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar': {display: 'none' } }}/>
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work for me :(

Answer (score -2):

I have tested your code, and even though for me there was no scrollbar at the bottom of that table, I think you might try adding "hideScrollbar={true}" to the DataGrid options. This should remove the scrollbar from the bottom of the DataGrid component.

```js
<DataGrid
     rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    autoHeight={true}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
    pageSize={5}
    disableSelectionOnClick
    density="compact"
    hideFooterPagination={true}
    hideFooter={true}
    showCellRightBorder={true}
    showColumnRightBorder={true}
    hideScrollbar={true}
/>
```

The second option that I am thinking is to remove it with CSS by giving that DataGrid a className like "myTable" and in the CSS do this:

```css
.myTable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

If after this the issue isn't fixed, please check your additional CSS or you can upload it here; I would be happy to help you.

For the record here is where I tested your code: https://playcode.io/1191293

Here is also the live preview for that: https://1191293.playcode.io/

Hope this was helpful, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I haven't used 'react-data-grid', I have used material UI DataGrid component and in that, we don't have the 'hideScrollBar' prop to turn off. for more info please refer this: https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#props